# Using ffmpeg to cut audio from/to position

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, cut

I need to cut parts from an audio file from position to position.  When I tried this command

```
ffmpeg -ss 132 -t 139 -i original.mp3 new.mp3
```

it started at the second 132, and added the next 139 seconds to the new file.

What I need is from second 132 to second 139.

And when I tried

```
ffmpeg -ss 132 -to 139 -i original.mp3 new.mp3
```

it gives me an error:

```
Unrecognized option 'to'
Failed to set value '139' for option 'to'
```

(I don't want to tell how many seconds to take, just from/to).

--
I have ffmpeg version 0.8.20-6:0.8.20-0+deb7u1 (built on Jan 19 2017 11:13:36 with gcc 4.7.2). And when I try to update it (apt-get install ffmpeg), it tells me "ffmpeg is already the newest version".

Answer (score 120, accepted):

With FFmpeg the ordering of parameters is significant.  All of the parameters that come directly before an input will apply to that input.  The same is true for an output... the parameters directly before it apply to the output.

Consider this command line:

```
ffmpeg -ss 132 -i input.mp3 output.mp3
```

`-ss` is the parameter to seek, so FFmpeg will seek the input file to 132 seconds in and treat that effectively at `00:00:00`.  The rest of your FFmpeg commands relative to the output don't know or care where that input came from or how it was seeked.  Therefore, when you use `-to` or `-t`, the times or lengths given need to be **relative to the input**.  That is, if you want seconds 132 through 139, you want to seek the input to 132 (`-ss 132 -i input.mp3`), and then run the output for 7 seconds (`-t 7 output.mp3` or `-to 00:00:07 output.mp3`).

You can read more about this, as well as details about frame-accurate or not (for re-encoding or not) on the documentation:  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

As for `-to` not being there...

> As I shown above, I have the latest version of the software.

You absolutely positively do **not** remotely have the latest version of FFmpeg.  You might have the latest build of whatever branch whatever package manager has, and it may have been built this year, but if you check the download page, the latest release as of this writing is 3.3.4.  https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

You can either deal with your package manager and dependency hell, or depending on your licensing restrictions, snag a recent static build:  https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Finally, consider `-acodec copy` to ensure you're not hurting the quality of  your audio further by transcoding, since you're keeping the same format.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know you were sensitive to minor edits to improve accuracy.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm not, but that was more than a minor edit, didn't add anything of substance to what I already wrote, and added some additional opinions from you that would have been attributed to me.  (Not that I disagree with you re:bugginess and what not.  I just would have preferred you kept the commentary as a comment attributed to you.)

Comment: `ffmpeg -ss <T0> -i <input file> -t <T1 - T0(duration in seconds)> <out file>` or `ffmpeg -ss <T0> -i <input file> -t <T0(format 00:00:00) + (T1 - T0)> <out file>` for example `ffmpeg -ss 00:15:30 -i "a.mp3" -t 25 "b.mp3"` or `ffmpeg -ss 00:15:30 -i "a.mp3" -t 00:00:25 "b.mp3"`

Comment: My tests seem to suggest that if I use `-to` to specify the ending time, I need to put `-i input` before `-ss`, e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ss 00:01:30 -to 00:02:50 output.mp3`

Answer (score 62):

This works for me

```
ffmpeg -ss 60 -i input-audio.aac -t 15 -c copy output.aac
```

- **-ss 60** means, "start from second 60"
- **-t 15** audio output length in seconds.. in this case, 15 seconds..

Answer (score 15):

```
ffmpeg -i "original.mp3" -ss 60 -to 70 "new.mp3"
```

This works for me.

Comment: Note that this is a highly inefficient way to seek.  It's far more efficient to seek the input before starting the output.

Comment: @Brad that depends on what the original poster wanted. Putting -ss before -i means the seek happens first and it is a quicker way of arriving at the starting timestamp. However, this may not always produce a frame accurate cut. If you are using ffmpeg 2.1 or greater then -ss before -i will be fast, since -ss is now frame accurate. See this link for more details https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Answer (score 14):

`-ss` is an input option, while `-t` and `-to` are output options. So you need to do this:

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 60 -i 'les nuits 128k.m4a' -to 70 -c copy out.m4a
```

Comment: it gave me an error: Unrecognized option 'to', Failed to set value '139' for option 'to' - and didn't create an output file

Comment: @Mike that was added 4 years ago, so that is your problem http://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/2d70446

Comment: As I shown above, I have the latest version of the software. So what do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

To Trim Audio file using **FFmpeg**

startDuration = 00:00:00, 
endDuration = 00:00:10

audioPath = audio.mp3,
mp3Output = outputFile.mp3

> cmd = "-ss $startDuration -i $audioPath -c copy -t $endDuration $mp3Output"

Answer (score 0):

for Mac:

```
brew install ffmpeg

ffmpeg -ss start_second -to end_second -i input.mp3 output.mp3
```